# Servlets and JSPs: Adding parameters to a href that routes to a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

everyone.

I am looking for a way to add a parameter to a url that linked directly to a servlet.  That is, the application that I am creating uses one Servlet to route people through the application it self.  It looks for a parameter called action, and from that, it decides where the user will go.

The problem is that the link that I am using to link to a dashboard page calls a servlet that I called Router within the href itself.  I thought that I could just use the following code to add an action parameter and set it to dashboard:

```
<a href="Router?action=dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

However, this doesn't work.  I need a way to add the parameter to the link itself that way I can process which page the user is trying to access.

Here is my code for both the JSP that I am using and the Servlet that is used to route the users around.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="Router?action=dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            </ul>
```

And here os the Servlet code:

```
String action = (String)request.getAttribute("action");

    User user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");

    String url = "home.jsp";

    boolean user_auth = user.getUserAuth();



    switch(action) {
        case "home":
         request.setAttribute("user", user);
         request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
         break;
        case "dashboard":
            if(user.getUserAuth()) {
                url = "dashboard.jsp";

                out.println("You've been authed");
                //request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
            } else {
                out.println("You're NOT authed.");
                //request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
            }
            break;
        default: 
            request.getRequestDispatcher("404Error.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

This is a pretty simple and straight forward application, and its meet to be that way since I'm just starting to learn.  But I would just like to know how to add the parameter straight to the url in the href.

If there is no way of doing this, can you offer a better solution to this issue?  Should I be using a separate Servlet to process this request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exception you  are getting?

Comment: getAttribute or getParameter ?

Comment: use request.getParemeter("action");

Answer (score 2):

If you're setting a parameter in the link, you can't use `getAttribute()` in your Servlet. Probally, you're getting a **NullPointerException**.

What you must to is use `getParameter("action")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your case use `request.getParameter("action");`  and also you can use form and hidden form field to send some static values to servlet.

**Hidden form field**

```
<form action="./Router" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="dashboard" />
<button type="submit">Dashboard</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, guys.  Thanks.

Comment: If it works for you then you can accept my answer, by selecting tick symbol left side of answer below up down arrow.